# I'm stuck in Creative and God mode and lost in the Nether. How can I get out?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was playing on a multiplayer server with the owner and had been given OP privileges.

I had turned on Creative mode and activated the 'God' command, but before the owner left, he de-opped me. Now I can not get out of Creative or God mode.

So I've tried:

- Killing myself & falling into the void
- Going to the middle of the nether with coordinates.
- Making a portal but I can not light up the portal (Multiplayer server rules).

None of which worked.

Finally I wait for another player to come online, but the player is also not an op so I cannot teleport to him.

Please help me! The only thing I can do is to wait for the Owner of the server!

Comment: Can you get the other player to teleport to the Nether, send you the coordinates, and teleport to those coordinates? If he can get to the Nether then he should be near a portal

Comment: Does the tpx command work in vanilla? I don't play vanilla so I haven't the foggiest idea whether or not it is available.

Answer (score 1):

If you have creative mode simply make a portal.

Creative gives you the ability to get the obsidian and you can light the portal using a log and a lava source to set the log on fire. or if you can use flint and steel but you are not meant to. tbh in your situation i would do it and as soon as you see an OP explain to him what happened and be honest about it. They will understand the issue and why you had to do that.

Just make a portal anywhere in the nether and then you can fly back to your base when you are out of it.

There is a way to kill yourself as well. dig as low as you possibly can and under the bedrock floor. once below it be sure to patch the bedrock back in so it doesn't  cause other problems. and then just fall into the void.

Comment: He mentioned that he could not light up the portal due to server rules.

Comment: which i addressed in my answer with my various options

Comment: Welp, read over it too quickly and thought you just told him to light it on fire. Sorry about that.